# Filter hyperlinks from web page and download all that match a certain pattern

Tags: grep, wget, curl, download, filter

I wanted to download all graphic files from our organisation's graphics repository web page.  They are Illustrator (*.ai) format and Corel Draw (*.cdr) format.

They are directly hyperlinked (i.e. `<a href="http://server/path-to-file.ai">...</a>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`wget` includes features to support this directly:

```
wget -r -A "*.ai,*.cdr" 'address-of-page-with-hyperlinks'
```

`-r` enables recursive mode so it will download more than the given URL, and `-A` limits the files it will download and keep in the end.

Comment: Nice, I knew about `wget`'s spidering capabilities but never knew it had such a nice filtering option!

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the page with `curl`
2. Filter for hyperlinks with `grep`.  Note that this exploits the fact that they are all formatted consistently (as `<a href="..."`).  An [HTML/XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461737/how-to-execute-xpath-one-liners-from-shell) really [should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1156377) for anything even slightly more complicated.
3. Cut the hyperlink address out with `grep -o`, filtering with `grep` again to extract only links who's target has the desired extension(s) and protocol(s).
4. Download those resulting files with `wget` (or `curl` could also be used if output was specified).  Also, we `echo` the URL to the the console.

Note that our filtering in the script is not in the exact same order as above, for convenience.

**Bash**:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url; do
    # Echo URL to terminal
    echo "${url}"
    # Download files
    wget -q "${url}"
done < <(
    # Get page
    curl -s 'address-of-page-with-hyperlinks' | \
    # Filter hyperlinks
    grep -Po 'href="http://[^"]+\.(cdr|ai)"' | \
    grep -Po 'http://[^"]+'
)
```